# Macro not autorunning upon open

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim WB As Workbook

Set WB = ActiveWorkbook


WB.Sheets("Automation").Range("U23:W467").Select

Selection.ClearContents

End Sub
```

From what I can gather from SO, this code should automatically clear contents in those cells when I open the workbook. However, it doesn't. When I step into the code everything works fine and the cells are cleared.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Seems legit to me. Do you have security against macros?

Comment: I went to macro security and checked enable all macros, still nada

Comment: Quick tip, you can [avoid using `.Select`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) by just combining your two lines to `WB.Sheets("Automation").Range("U23:W467").ClearContents`.  This should work though, are you perhaps in a read-only mode? Or have something preventing macros from being run?  When you say it doesn't clear the contents, what happens?  Try removing `.Select` and see if that does it.

Comment: I'm not using range because these are merged cells, select works better. When I say it doesn't clear the contents, I mean when I open the workbook, the cells still have info on it

Comment: Really? Using `.Select` works better for merged cells?  Interesting. I've always avoided Merged Cells, since they can be a headache, and that's another reason for me to avoid them.  Thanks for that info!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where is the code for sub `Workbook_Open()` placed?

If you put it in the `ThisWorkbook` class it should run.

If you have it in a regular code module it will not run with that name, but you could call the sub `Auto_Open()` instead and it should run automatically.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know I had to put that into `thisworkbook` class